# Backup microsoft SQL server 2008 to OneDrive

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008, cloud

Is there an option to automate a backup to Microsoft Onedrive every night? The machine is a Windows server 2008 R2. I would like to to able to automatically upload my backups to OneDrive. I was wondering if there is an option to do so automatically.

If it's not possible, how about naming the backup files by date each time its backups and just dropping the backups in a OneDrive folder?

I decided on OneDrive because its the cheaper cloud I know for now 1TB for $6.99 a month. And soon they will introduce the unlimited plans.

Comment: You can simply use SqlBak tool to backup your database and then send backups to OneDrive http://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-backup-database-sql/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to schedule a SQL Server backup to the folder of your choice, including Onedrive.  If you don't already have backups scheduled for your SQL Server, I recommend [Ola Hallengren's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html).  You should be able to just install the scripts and edit the jobs it creates to point to the folder of your choice and schedule them the way you want (such as nightly).  The backups are dated in the filename by default, and the scripts include a cleanup option.

Don't forget to back up your transaction logs, too, if your databases are set to full recovery.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, SQL backup jobs end to be really picky about their connection to the target device, and will often fail over a network link.  Any network link.  Even, say, between two VMs on the same blade server.  So I'd advise a bunch of trial runs on this first before putting down any money for a cloud storage solution that your SQL backup jobs might or might be able to actually use.  (I've had much more success having the SQL backup job target a local disk, and then using a script to move the backup files to a remote location, FYI.)

Comment: The "available offline" option on the directory in question might (not guaranteed) help with that.  I'm backing up multiple (dev/qa) servers to a remote location (not OneDrive) and haven't experienced any issues, but you're right that it does happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I think [AutoVer](http://beanland.net.au/AutoVer/) would work well for this. It has versioning of backups.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Is there a way though, to do it without a 3rd party software? From SQL server